# Convert antlr grammar to other format ( i.e xsd, dtd )

Tags: xsd, antlr, dtd

I would like to marshall/unmarshall a grammar of a language using JAXB, so I need a DTD/XSD file. Is it possible to convert ANTLR grammars to these formats? The BNF Converter https://bnfc.digitalgrammars.com/ can generate dtd for LBNF